# Stop Typescript compiler from trying to compile files inside node_modules (SFPX React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsconfig, spfx, tsc

I am working on an SPFX (SharePoint Framework) React application.
After installing the popular automapper for typescript (@automapper/core @automapper/pojos) I keep getting compiler errors during `gulp build`:

[image]

My tsConfig.json looks like the following:

[image]

I am using rush-stack-compiler 4.2 which is using typescript 4.2.4 behind the scenes.

Things I have tried based on the answers from other questions:

1. Upgrade typescript version - in SPFX this is done by upgrading the rush-stack-compiler from 3.7 to 4.2
   This helped only a little, as there are LESS type errors from the @automapper library, but not all of them were fixed.
2. Add `"exclude": [ "node_modules" ]` to the tsConfig.json
3. Add `"skipLibCheck": true` to the tsConfig.json
4. Specified empty `"types": []` setting in tsConfig.json

Any idea why tsc is looking specifically into the node_modules/@automapper folder, although there are hundreds of other folders in node_modules with the *.d.ts files, that are not a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating typescript to 4.5: `@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-4.5`

It looks like the @automatpper is using bleeding-edge typescript features. The problem is not related to inclusion/exclusion of the `node_modules`, it seems to be related to the typescript version (you seem to have installed an older version that does not understand some definitions of the automapper).

Alternatively, use an older version of the automapper (7.x should probably be okay)

Comment: Downgrading to version 7.x solved the issue for me.